# Does Groovy 2.5 support Java 13?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to understand if Apache Groovy 2.5 (latest stable release) supports Java 13. As per [System Requirements](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html#requirements) page it should be fine to use any JDK 1.7+.

However when I try to compile my Spock tests with Gradle 6 on Java 13 I get the following error:

```
Caused by: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' 
  in source unit '/home/myself/project/Test.groovy' 
  Unsupported class file major version 57
```

Could it be due to [GROOVY-9020](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9020) or is Apache Groovy 2.5 not officially supporting Java 13?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating to Groovy 2.5.7 or newer solves the problem. In my case transitive Spock dependencies used an older version of Groovy.

The root cause was ASM library which was reported in [GROOVY-9020](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9020) and [GROOVY-9055](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9055) and fixed in [upgraded ASM to 7.1, added Java 13 to CompilerConfiguration #887](https://github.com/apache/groovy/pull/887) pull request.

Reported the issue under [Update Spock 1.3-groovy-2.5 to support Java 13 #1051](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1051).